# How can I represent foreign keys in templates?

Tags: python, django

How I can represent foreign keys in templates?

***Models.py***

```
class Trabajo(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150)
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to='perfiles', verbose_name = 'Small image')
    descripcion = models.TextField()
    fecha = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150)
    link = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150)
    cliente = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.titulo

class Imagen(models.Model):
    titulo_proyecto = models.ForeignKey(Trabajo, related_name='+')
    imagenes = models.ImageField(upload_to='perfiles', verbose_name = 'Imagen')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.titulo_proyecto)
```

***Views.py***

```
def index(request):
    trabajos = Trabajo.objects.all()
    imagenes = Imagen.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'works': trabajos, 'images': imagenes})
```

***index.html***

```
{% for item in works %}

    {% for obj in item.images.all %}
        {{obj.imagenes}}
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'represent foreign keys'? What do you want the user to see?

Comment: The images(Model Imagen) that are of X work(Model Trabajo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Views.py***

```
  def index(request):
        trabajos = Trabajo.objects.all()
        imagenes = Imagen.objects.all()
        return render_to_response('index.html', {'works': trabajos, 'images': imagenes})
```

***index.html***

```
 {% for item in works %}
         {{item.id}} 
         {% for obj in images %}
              {% ifequal item.id obj.titulo_proyecto_id %}
                   {{item.id}} <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{obj.imagenes}}" />
              {% endifequal %}
         {% endfor %}

 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: It's not working because I put images instead of imagen. I updated my answer. I hope this works now

Comment: This will hit the database once per item in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I know what you mean. First, you should clean up your view so it doesn't hit the database more often than it needs to. Change:

```
trabajos = Trabajo.objects.all()
imagenes = Imagen.objects.all()
```

to:

```
trabajos = Trabajo.objects.all().select_related()
```

Now try:

```
{% for item in works.imagen_set.all %}
    <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ item }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Doesn't work :(
{% for item in works.titulo_proyecto_set.all %}
    <li class="iit_{{item.id}} pic"><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ item }}" alt="{{item.titulo}}" />
{% endfor %}

Comment: Does anything not work in particular? If you don't give details it's hard to help. What rendered? Have you tried working on this in a shell?

Comment: Try the edited version, I think I got the model name wrong. Better still, try running `python manage.py shell` and importing your models to see what gets what you need and what doesn't.